# How do I call a ansible playbook sitting on a docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, ansible

I've two docker containers A and B. I've a playbook1 on container A and playbook2 on container B. Now, how do i call/execute playbook2 from playbook1?

Note:- These two containers are on two different machines in two different VPCs.

Comment: Can we assume that there is a route between these two containers?

Comment: yes, they have a communication established

Comment: Do you want to include playbook2 in playbook1 or do you want playbook1 to invoke ansible on the remote host to run playbook2?

Comment: i want to include playbook2 in playbook1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to resolve this issue by adding below code sinnper in the playbook1 which is sitting on container1

> - name: Execute playbook
>     hosts: container_host2
>     gather_facts: true
>     tasks:
>
>   - shell: docker exec --workdir {{path_of_playbooks_on_container2}} {{platform_tools_container_name}} ansible-playbook -i
>       {{relative_inventory_file_path}} playbook2.yaml
>
>     register: output